# what is the scale of TF-IDF results?

Tags: neural-networks, scales, tf-idf

I did a classification of review text data using the ANN model. As we know, text data must be converted into numeric first before entering the classification stage. To change this I used the TF-IDF method. I am confused whether the data scale of TF-IDF results is a ratio or interval scale.
Here's the example of TF-IDF result:
[image]
doc 1 = It is going to rain today
doc 2 = Today I am not going outside
doc 3 = I am going to watch the season premiere

the result of TF-IDF every word can be 0 to infinity

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the definitions made in [this](https://www.questionpro.com/blog/ratio-scale-vs-interval-scale) article, the most important difference between an interval-scale variable and a ratio-scale variable is the notion of absolute zero point:

> Zero-point in an interval scale is arbitrary. For example, the
> temperature can be below 0 degrees Celsius and into negative
> temperatures.

> The ratio scale has an absolute zero or character of origin. Height
> and weight cannot be zero or below zero.

The TF-IDF has a notion of absolute zero, when the term does not appear in the any document, i.e. term-frequency is $0$. It is, therefore, a ratio-scale variable.